# Synaptics driver doesn't load sometimes

Tags: boot, drivers, upstart, synaptics

Sometimes (randomly), the synaptics touchpad driver won't load on bootup. When reading `/var/log/boot.log`, i don't see anything touchpad-driver-like being started when this happens.

But the file `/dev/input/mouse0` exists and I can perform simple actions with my mousepad (pointing, clicking, but no scrolling) and the pointer speed is very low when moving it via the touchpad.

When typing `synclient` into terminal while this is happening, it tells me `Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`

Whats the problem here?

Comment: Touchpad procession of Xorg is done by `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. So i doubt it will have an effect.

Comment: Sorry, did you try reinstall it?

Comment: Yes, both `input-mouse` ans `input-synaptics`. But I can only tell after a few days whether it worked.

Comment: Try : `sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` . Purging is needed to remove malconfiguration.

Comment: Going out on a limb here as it's one of those pesky "sometimes" errors.  Have you tried moving the synaptics /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/5?-synaptics*.conf to /etc/X11/xorg.conf as "the X Server treats the collection of configuration files as one big file with entries from xorg.conf at the end" (from the manual) and I'm suspecting a timing-based issue...
(And no one has provided any suggestion in nearly a year nor provided this feed-back)

Comment: Potentially [duplicate issue?][1]. Can you try the workaround from that question?


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/579293/couldnt-find-synaptics-properties-after-reboot-no-synaptics-driver-loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started having this problem after upgrading from 12.04 to 14.04. Tried purging / reinstalling xserver-xorg-input-synaptics, but the problem persisted. I decided to browse the available packages in Synaptic Package Manager, and found this:

`xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-trusty`

I installed it alongside the other ("generic") package. Hopefully this fixes the issue.

Comment: I fail to see how a "Hopefully" was accepted as the answer.  SE is meant to form a knowledge base, but I came to this high search-ranked thread expecting info, and the accepted answer tells me nothing. Did that package solve this? for you or the OP? Still, since I have the same problem on Debian 8.2, installing a Ubuntu specific version is not an option for me (which, sorry, but makes this even less useful).