# twofinger scroll on lenovo g50

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

I recently switched from windows 8 to Ubuntu 14.04. With windows I could scroll pages using two fingers but this does not work running Ubuntu.

I have followed this guide:
[Enable BOTH edge scrolling and two-finger scrolling for touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248290/enable-both-edge-scrolling-and-two-finger-scrolling-for-touchpad/248304#248304)

but the commands only gives me the message:
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

Any idea what to do?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

This instructions solved the issue for me on a Lenovo G50 + Mint Cinnamon 17

http://www.evilcodingmonkey.com/2014/01/23/ubuntu-activate-multi-touch-on-elantech/

Copy-paste (code typo fixed and a bit more of info added), as backup

> First, if you aren't sure your computer was built with an Elantech
>   touchpad, open a terminal, and type the following:
>
> ```
> cat /proc/bus/input/devices
> ```
>
> You should find a block containing a line looking like this one, which confirms you are on an Elantech touchpad:
>
> ```
> N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> N: Name="PS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
> ```
>
> Download [this archive](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1166442/+attachment/3941591/+files/psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz) (from Ubuntu's bug reporting page).
>
> Open a terminal, and follow these steps (after step 4, you will have
>   no mouse at all):
>
> ```
> cd ~/Downloads 
> sudo dkms ldtarball psmouse-elantech-x551c.tar.gz 
> sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v elantech-x551c 
> sudo rmmod psmouse 
> sudo modprobe psmouse
> ```
>
> Enjoy multitouch!

Comment: This works for me. But just until the next startup. After a reboot I don't have multitouch. But if I call `sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse, then everything works again. Any tips?

Comment: No, sorry, it worked for me even after reboot. You should probably start a new question with more info about your system.

Answer (score 0):

Is the package xserver-xorg-input-synaptics installed ?

If not try to install it using the terminal by typing the command below:

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics

Comment: Thank you for the response.

it is allready installed

Comment: Have you tried this suggesstion from (http://askubuntu.com/questions/396422/synaptics-driver-doesnt-load-sometimes): sudo apt-get purge xserver-xorg-input-synaptics && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synapticg

Answer (score 0):

Actually I had a same problem the only solution that I come up with is just install Gpointing device setting (you can find this in ubuntu software center) and enable there touchpad settings (u can customize quite a lot there), although afterwards my right click is not working :) I'll try to figure out that also
and reboot your computer after installation

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the answer here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1407785/comments/26

Download the file: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1407785/+attachment/4309044/+files/psmouse-elantech-x551c-G50-70.tar.gz

and then the following commands via the terminal:

```
sudo dkms ldtarball psmouse-elantech-x551c-G50-70.tar.gz
sudo dkms install -m psmouse -v elantech-x551c-G50-70

sudo rmmod psmouse
sudo modprobe psmouse
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest kernel with well. Touchpad is stable and smooth

> wget \
>
> kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-rc2+cod1-wily/linux-headers-4.4.0-040400rc2_4.4.0-040400rc2.201511231054_all.deb \
>
> kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-rc2+cod1-wily/linux-headers-4.4.0-040400rc2-generic_4.4.0-040400rc2.201511231054_amd64.deb \
>
> kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4-rc2+cod1-wily/linux-image-4.4.0-040400rc2-generic_4.4.0-040400rc2.201511231054_amd64.deb
>
> sudo dpkg -i linux-headers-4.4*.deb linux-image-4.4*.deb
>
> update-grub