# Scroll on touch pad is not working, Lenovo G50

Tags: 14.04, touchpad, lenovo

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit on my Lenovo laptop and scroll is not working on the touchpad.

When I try to look at it in settings, there is no Touchpad panel at all. (I guess it recognizes my Touchpad as a mouse.)

I tried to follow the following [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/519696/twofinger-scroll-on-lenovo-g50) but it says that there is no dkms command. So I am kind of desperate, can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx Fabby for the comment, that solves my problem with dkms but touchpad still was not working. 
I just was able to solve it by installing Gpointing Device Settings from Ubuntu Software Center and enable scrolling on touchpad from there.

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happened to me.
You just have to install dkms:

```
sudo apt install dkms
```

Comment: thx a lot, this solved my problem with dkms and I was able to install the file mentioned above in the solution link, but still my touchpad is not working