# Couldn't find synaptics properties after reboot. No synaptics driver loaded?

Tags: drivers, touchpad, synaptic, elantech

Every time I reboot my laptop, my touchpad scrolling stops to work. I assume it's because my synaptics isn't loading as when I try to run `synclient`. I get the

> Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

error. In addition, my touchpad is read as a P2 Generic Mouse, instead of ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad.

To fix it I just run `sudo rmmod psmouse` and `sudo modprobe -v psmouse`. and everything is back to normal. How can I make the change permanent?

Comment: Fix did not work for me.  2015 RB on 14.04

Comment: Yes, same here and fix works for me on 14.04. I think this is a kernel issue as this has only started after upgrade to 3.13.0-48. Can you verify your kernel version (uname -a)?

Comment: @BartoszRadaczyński, I'm using 3.16.0-031600-generic.

Comment: refer [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/644411/couldnt-find-synaptics-properties-no-synaptics-driver-loaded)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to automatically load the `psmouse` module at boot edit the `/etc/modules` file, and add it there.

```
sudo gedit /etc/modules
```

and add it to a new line there.