# No Synaptics Touchpad Drivers

Tags: drivers, ati, touchpad, synaptic, synaptics

So in an attempt to install the fglrx-updates package I somehow managed to disable my touchpad. I've gone through all the things I can think of. I tried reinstalling the xorg drivers via:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

And it's not the same issue as here: 
[Couldn't find synaptics properties after reboot. No synaptics driver loaded?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579293/couldnt-find-synaptics-properties-after-reboot-no-synaptics-driver-loaded)

It might help to know I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on an HP dv6117

It might also help to know it stopped working after running this:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends xserver-xorg libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa-drivers
```

And also when I try to run synclient it returns:

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?
```

The computer still works fine with my wireless mouse, but I'd prefer to get the touchpad working again.

**EDIT**

I had restarted the computer several times in the process of trying to find the cause and randomly the touchpad became operable probably about the 7th time. I checked BIOS settings and there is nothing even relating to the touchpad. There also isn't a normal Fn key combination to disable the touchpad on my laptop. Even though it's working I'd still like to know what disabled it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if it is useful, but please check the BIOS settings, if touchpad is disabled there?

Also, many notebooks have Fn+key combination to disable the TP. Couldn't you press this combination unintentionally?

Try to boot from LiveCD - does it detect the TP?