# Ubuntu 14.04 - mouse can click, but cannot move

Tags: 14.04

My desktop broke down so I reinstalled `ubuntu-desktop`, `unity` and `nvidia-current`. Changed own permission of `/home` just in case. Desktop problem is fixed but...now my cursor can click, but cannot move.

I've tried:

- `sudo apt-get -f install` such apt commands.
- `sudo reboot`, stays the same.
- `sudo modprobe psmouse` to reload.

They didn't fix.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is, we don't have a (properly) working driver.

1. In [this case](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/214) the touchpad doesn't move because the value to trigger the gesture is high.
2. In [the second case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/396422/synaptics-driver-doesnt-load-sometimes) we can handle the issue by installing an extra working drive.

So, solution is run

```
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-lts-trusty
```

logout,

```
gnome-session-quit
```

and everthing's going to work.